# Get command line path from which EXE was called

Tags: command-line, path, exe

This seems like an easy question, but I can't seem to get how to do this. Here's my situation.

I made an executable file in a folder in my `PATH`. For simplicity's sake, let's say that it is named `create_hello` and looks at the place from which it was called and creates a file named `hello.txt`. The file-creation is handled by the EXE. The problem is getting the place from which the EXE was called.

Here's an example.

```
root
|- folder
```

Imagine I'm calling `create_hello` from the command line in `root/folder`. This is what I expect to see.

```
root
|- folder
   |- hello.txt
```

I've tried accessing the environment arguments passed to the EXE file, but it shows the path where the EXE file is located, not from where the EXE file was invoked.

I'd like it to work in mainly Windows.

I don't think the language is relevant here, but if it turns out to be relevant, I'm using Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::env::current_dir` returns the current working directory:

directly from [current_dir](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html) doc page:

```
use std::env;

// We assume that we are in a valid directory.
let path = env::current_dir().unwrap();
println!("The current directory is {}", path.display());
```